# pymysql - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I wrote this code in python3 using pymysql:

```
statement = """INSERT INTO weather_1 (temperature, pressure) VALUES(?,?)"""
cur.execute(statement, (temp1, press,))
```

Error:

```
File "main.py", line 39, in insert_data
cur.execute(statement, (temp1, press,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 168, in execute
query = self.mogrify(query, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 147, in mogrify
query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I tried to convert all variables, but I still have this Error.

Comment: What type do these two variables `temp1` and `press` have?

Comment: As far as I know the place holder for pymysql is not `?` but `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

Use %s instead of ? as suggested at https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/78

Comment: Try to explain where OP should use %s. Show example instead of a link.